# How to get server response code for each request in WebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview

I have authorization logic managed via WebView:

- user click on login button in app
- I open WebView with loading login webpage (opened by url address)
- user provide their login and password > click on login button on page
- next page is opened in WebView - authorize access confirmation page
- user has to click on authorize access button on webpage
- after this redirect_uri URL will be tried to be opened in WebView
- I catch this redirect_uri in request and close WebView

I inspect all requests (in order to catch redirect_uri) in WebView delegate method `shouldStartLoadWithRequest:`.

Question: how can I manage server response for each request for page opened in WebView?

The point is that we have some problems with auth server and time to time it shows error pages. So I want to catch such pages and close WebView for such cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

found the solution via `WKWebView`.
I connected it the same way as `UIWebView` worked in my project.

And then I actually use 2 methods from `WKNavigationDelegate` protocol:

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler
```

and

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationResponse:(WKNavigationResponse *)navigationResponse decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationResponsePolicy))decisionHandler
```

Example of code:

first method is to check whether current request is actually our `redirect_uri` that we should handle:

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler {
    NSLog(@"request: %@", navigationAction.request);

    // check whether this request should be stopped - if this is redirect_uri (like user is already authorized)
    if (...) {
        self.webView.navigationDelegate = nil;

        // do what is needed to send authorization data back
        self.completionBlock(...);

        // close current view controller
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

        // stop executing current request
        decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyCancel);

    } else {
        // otherwise allow current request
        decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyAllow);
    }
}
```

second method is to analyse response from server, and here we can verify the status code in order to handle any errors

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationResponse:(WKNavigationResponse *)navigationResponse decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationResponsePolicy))decisionHandler {
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)navigationResponse.response;

    // filter the responses, in order to verify only the response from specific domain
    if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:[[response URL] absoluteString]] containsString:@"some.domain.com/"]) {

        NSInteger statusCode = [response statusCode];

        // check what is the status code
        if (statusCode == 200 ||
            statusCode == 301 ||
            statusCode == 302) {

            // allow response as everything is ok
            decisionHandler(WKNavigationResponsePolicyAllow);

        } else {
            // handle the error (e.g. any of 4xx or any others)

            self.webView.navigationDelegate = nil;

            // send needed info back
            self.completionBlock(...);

            // close current view controller
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

            // stop current response
            decisionHandler(WKNavigationResponsePolicyCancel);
        }

    } else {
        // current response is not from our domain, so allow it
        decisionHandler(WKNavigationResponsePolicyAllow);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that this method will be called when the response statuscode is 301 or 302? I'm trying this and never receive these codes

Comment: these http status codes mean that request was redirected to another url. You will get them in rare cases (it depends on server itself). 
In most cases you'll get status code 200

Comment: for me it was very important to catch 4xx or 5xx errors as authorization server can be down very often at my project ))

Comment: sorry but this answer is misleading. The response delegate method is never called for 302 HTTP responses.

Comment: you can put any http status code here you want to allow or filter - I didn't know how to do that with `WebView` delegate.
But I've found answer via using `WKWebView` and `WKNavigationDelegate`.

Comment: As others say, this will NOT catch 302's .. So it's not really a suitable answer

Answer (score 1):

Implement below delegate method might be work for you.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSCachedURLResponse *urlResponse = [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] cachedResponseForRequest:webView.request];
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*) urlResponse.response;
    NSInteger statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode;
    NSLog(@"%@",statusCode);
}
```

Comment: `decidePolicyForNavigationResponse` works better as I can catch server errors before they displayed on screen and show more user-friendly message

Answer (score 0):

In swift, you can try and cast the URLResponse to HTTPURLResponse to get the statusCode field.

```
extension MyController: WKNavigationDelegate {
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse,
                 decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void) {
       
        if let httpResponse = navigationResponse.response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode
            //....
        }
        decisionHandler(.allow)
}
```

}